# telnet over SSH from server

Tags: python, ssh, telnet

I am doing ssh to a server using parmiko in python. From there, I need to telnet to several devices and capture the output. I am able to ssh and then telnet to only one device but not ablke to telnet multiple devices from a loop. please suggest me how to do this.
I am using the following

```
import paramiko
import telnetlib

ip = ''
port = 42705
username = ''
password = ''

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip,port,username,password)

f=open("abc.txt", "r")
x=f.readlines()
i=1
if i < 100:
  print i
  cmd = "telnet " + x[i]
  print cmd
  i=i+1


stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
stdin.write('''
terminal length 0
show platform
exit
''')

outlines = stdout.readlines()
resp = ''.join(outlines)
print(resp)
```

when I am not using if statement and directly giving ip, its working good. But I need to telnet multiple devices from same server. Thanks for your reply!

I am now using the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import paramiko


ip=''
port=42705
username=''
password=''
f1=open("abc.txt", 'r')
devices=f1.readlines()

for device in devices:
   device = device.rstrip()
   print device
   command = "telnet " + device
   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
   print command
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)
   stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
   stdin.write('''
   primenms
   primenms123
   terminal length 0
   show platform
   exit
   ls
   ''')
   outlines = stdout.readlines()
   resp = ''.join(outlines)
   print(resp)
   ssh.close()
```

f1.close()

It is able to ssh but when I am doing telnet from ssh server, its entering credentials primenms and primenms123 as username and password, which is correct credentials, but its showing as authorization failed. Where am I going wrong? Please help me guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should likely be using a `for` loop instead:

```
for i in f.readlines():
    cmd = "telnet {0}".format(i)
    print cmd
```

Ideally you'd want to execute the commands with:

```
ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

Then you could use it like the following example:

```
for i in f.readlines():
    cmd = "telnet {0}".format(i)
    ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

Without knowing what is within `abc.txt` you might need other ssh commands in there too.

Comment: Also, `ssh.exec_command(cmd)`, et al, should be inside the loop.

Comment: "abc.txt" just contains the list of ip addresses I want to telnet from within the ssh server. Also, when I am using ssh.exec_command(cmd) inside the loop, the program shows me authorization failed even though I am entering the right credentials.

Comment: How are you using the telnet command when not inside your loop? If it's just by the print statement then I'd say just use that.

Answer (score 0):

late answer on this, sorry.
For me it looks like your user and password just have leading spaces. You need to change

```
   stdin.write('''
   primenms
   primenms123
   terminal length 0
   show platform
   exit
   ls
   ''')
```

to

```
   stdin.write('''primenms
primenms123
terminal length 0
show platform
exit
ls
''')
```